# Getting the last Item of an collection

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Author  
{ 
    public int Id {set;get;}

    [Required]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public ICollection<Column> Columns {set;get;}

    public virtual File AuthorImage { set; get; }

}
```

I have above model. and I want to get all the authors and 1 Column for each. But I want the latest (last inserted id) column that per each.

Using DbContext, imagine I have `DbSet<Author> Authors`. What would be the correct linq for to get this?

for one Author, a LINQ query that returns the Column with the highest Id

Comment: What defines it as being the latest? Do you mean the latest ordered by Name?

Comment: Your wording is confusing. Could you restate what you are looking for?

Comment: Ordered by ID. Last inserted Column

Comment: Is it LINQ to Entities?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek doenst matter. I just need the query

Comment: What do you want the LINQ to return?  A collection of `Authors` where each author has 0 or 1 `Column` in its `Columns` collection?  Or, for one `Author`, a LINQ query that returns the `Column` with the highest Id?  Or something else?

Comment: @zigdawgydawg  for one Author, a LINQ query that returns the Column with the highest Id

Answer (score 2):

For one author, this finds the Column with the highest Id:

```
if (author.Columns != null && author.Columns.Count > 0) 
{
    Column c = author.Columns.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var authors = yourSet.Select(a => 
    new Author { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name, Columns = new[]{a.Columns.Last()}, 
                 AuthorImage = a.AuthorImage});
```

This has the disadvantage of remaking every author, but what can you do.

Comment: @MoreCrazy That's `LastOrDefault()`. `Last` will throw.

Comment: I don't like the idea of reusing `Author` class here. Why do you need `Columns` as `List<Column>`, when you know it will only hold one item?

Comment: exactly @MarcinJuraszek I second that.

Comment: I think you need to add `OrderBy(a => a.Id)` (according to "Ordered by ID. Last inserted Column " comment)

Comment: @MoreCrazy I thought that you wanted the same class?

Comment: `Last` returns an element, so it doesn't make sense to call `ToList` on it, does it?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen It does on the current `Author` class.

Comment: Let me put it differently then. Since `ToList` is defined for `IEnumerable<T>` and `Last` returns `T` it looks weird. Does `Column` implement `IEnumerable<T>`?